# Getting no output after running python program

Tags: python, class, python-2.x

I am supposed to write a class named Employee that holds the data of name, salary, and years of service. It calculates the monthly pension payout the employee will receive in retirement and display the three instance variables of the Employee objects. It also calls the Employee object’s pension method to calculate the monthly pension payout of this employee and also display it.

**I do not get any output after running my program and that is the specific problem.**

I am supposed to get something like this as the output:

```
Name: Joe Chen
Salary: 80000
Years of service: 30
Monthly pension payout: 3600.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is the full code.

```
class Employee:


    # init method implementation
    def __init__(self, EmpName, EmpSalary, EmpYos):
        self.EmpName = EmpName
        self.EmpSalary = EmpSalary
        self.EmpYos = EmpYos

    def displayEmployeeDetails(self):
        print "\nName ", self.EmpName,

    # defines the salary details
    def displaySalary(self):
        print "\nSalary", self.EmpSalary

    # defines the years of service
    def displayYoservice(self):
        print "\nYears of Service", self.EmpYos

    # defines pension
    def MonthlypensionPayout(self):
        print "\nMonthly Pension Payout:", self.EmpSalary * self.EmpYos * 0.0015


def main():


    # creates instance for employee 1
    Emplo1 = Employee("Joe Chen", 80000, 30)
    # creates instance for employee 2
    Emplo2 = Employee("Jean park", 60000, 25)

    # Function calls
    Emplo1.displayEmployeeDetails()
    Emplo1.displaySalary()
    Emplo1.displayYoservice()
    Emplo1.MonthlypensionPayout()
    # function calls
    Emplo2.displayEmployeeDetails()
    Emplo2.displaySalary()
    Emplo2.displayYoservice()
    Emplo2.MonthlypensionPayout()

main()
```

Comment: what is your python version?

Comment: remove the def main: and main()

Comment: @Exprator I think the version of Python is 2, because he prints without brackets.

Comment: Are you sure the methods of the Eployee class are tabbed in or are they on the very left? If latter is the case the methods are no party of the employee class.

Comment: Also, in the method displayEmployeeDetails you have a "," at the end. Not sure if it's supposed to be there.

Comment: @R.Gadeev: since the OP does not get any output, not even empty lines, I would suggest it's Python3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're just printing an empty line. Change your functions to the below:

```
def displayEmployeeDetails(self):

  print \
  "\nName ", self.EmpName

# defines the salary details
def displaySalary(self):


 print \
 "\nSalary", self.EmpSalary

# defines the years of service
def displayYoservice(self):


 print \
 "\nYears of Service", self.EmpYos
```

The `\` in python is line continuation. Better yet put all of it on the same line like so:

```
def displayEmployeeDetails(self):

  print "\nName ", self.EmpName

# defines the salary details
def displaySalary(self):


 print "\nSalary", self.EmpSalary

# defines the years of service
def displayYoservice(self):


 print "\nYears of Service", self.EmpYos
```

See the [demo](http://ideone.com/2e1d4b).